# Oracle SQL multi-value parameter - ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SSRS report with Oracle SQL query with parameter `v_acct_unit`. This parameter can be single value, multi value, or null. Please see the 3 query parameters below. The multi value parameter gives an error message. How can I resolve this error?

ERROR:

> ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

PARAMS-1 (Single) : 37 rows selected.

```
DEFINE V_BEG_DATE = "'080120'";
DEFINE V_END_DATE = "'080420'" ;
DEFINE V_ACCT_UNIT = "'0200301'" ;
```

PARAM-2 (Null) : Result 389 rows

```
DEFINE V_BEG_DATE = "'080120'";
DEFINE V_END_DATE = "'080420'" ;
DEFINE V_ACCT_UNIT = NULL ;
```

PARAM-3 (Multi) : ERROR

```
DEFINE V_BEG_DATE = "'080120'";
DEFINE V_END_DATE = "'080420'" ;
DEFINE V_ACCT_UNIT = "'0100001','0200301','',''" ;
```

SQL:

```
SELECT
    company company,
    acct_unit acct_unit,
    description description
FROM
    v_glnames names
WHERE
    ((&v_acct_unit) IS NULL OR acct_unit IN (&v_acct_unit))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is about *varying elements in *IN* list*. As it is a list, you can't use it as if it was a single value. One option is to split it to rows, using a hierarchical subquery. Here's an example:

```
SQL> select ename, job, sal
  2  from emp
  3  where ename in (select regexp_substr(replace(q'[&&par_ename]', chr(39), ''), '[^,]+', 1, level)
  4                  from dual
  5                  connect by level <= regexp_count(q'[&&par_ename]', ',') + 1
  6                 );
Enter value for par_ename: 'KING','','SCOTT','',''

ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- --------- ----------
SCOTT      ANALYST         3000
KING       PRESIDENT      10000

SQL>
```

Depending on a tool you use, parameter might be referenced as simple as `:par_ename`, but you should know it.

---

Another option might be this:

```
SQL> select ename, job, sal
  2  from emp
  3  where ename in (select *
  4                  from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('KING','','SCOTT','',''))
  5                 );

ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- --------- ----------
KING       PRESIDENT      10000
SCOTT      ANALYST         3000

SQL>
```